# In c# is there a way to test at runtime if a class overrides an operator

Tags: c#, overriding

I have a class that uses generics and I want to be able to test how one of those generic types "compare" to another.
I know I can have my class check if the type implements IComparable, and then utilize it's Compare method.
But is there any way to test at runtime if the type overrode the ">" greater than an less than operators?

I would imagine that there would be a way to do this using reflection. I couldn't find anything out there.

Comment: It's a little unclear how you plan to use this: if you're using a generic type you won't be able to use the `>` operator in your compile-time code. Are you hoping to invoke the operators using reflection?

Comment: If you write your program properly, it won't *compile* if the type doesn't have the operators you're using, so there's no need to check anything at runtime.

Comment: Are you trying to do codegen with this? I can't see why you're doing this otherwise. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can only identify them by convention as operator overloading is a language thing, not a CLR thing.  But something like

```
var ops = type.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.IsSpecialName && mi.Name.StartsWith("op_")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can verify the existence of the operator overloading, but as [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) reasoned in his comment already there is usually no point in doing so (except maybe code generation), since the compiler will check for that anyway and will throw error [CS0019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0019)) if you try to use operators when they are not defined:

```
Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'InvertLogic<int>' and 'InvertLogic<int>'
```

However, yes you can actually verify the existence of the methods at runtime using reflection, by checking for the method with the name `op_LessThanOrEqual` for the `<=` operator which is a method that the compiler will create for you. Other operators work conceptually the same way, but I'll focus on `<=` and `>=` here.

Take for example this class which defines `>=` and `<=` logically inverted:

```cs
public class InvertLogic<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public InvertLogic(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // Overriding >= operator
    public static bool operator >=(InvertLogic<T> left, InvertLogic<T> right)
    {
        return left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value) <= 0;
    }

    // Overriding <= operator
    public static bool operator <=(InvertLogic<T> left, InvertLogic<T> right)
    {
        return left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value) >= 0;
    }
}
```

When you look at the IL code and specifically you can find a the method `op_LessThanOrEqual`. Here just the declaration of the method:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static 
        bool op_LessThanOrEqual (
            class InvertLogic`1<!T> left,
            class InvertLogic`1<!T> right
        ) cil managed
```

> BTW: I've used [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io) to look at the IL code here.

So you can check for the existence of this method as you normally would with reflection:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var smallerValue = new InvertLogic<int>(0);
        var biggerValue = new InvertLogic<int>(1);

        var lessThanOrEqualMethod = typeof(InvertLogic<>)
            .GetMethod("op_LessThanOrEqual", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        PrintExists("op_LessThanOrEqual", lessThanOrEqualMethod);
        var greaterThanOrEqualMethod = typeof(InvertLogic<>)
            .GetMethod("op_GreaterThanOrEqual", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        PrintExists("op_GreaterThanOrEqual", greaterThanOrEqualMethod);

        Console.WriteLine($"Original: {smallerValue.Value <= biggerValue.Value}, " +
                          $"Inverted: {smallerValue <= biggerValue}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Original: {smallerValue.Value >= biggerValue.Value}, " +
                          $"Inverted: {smallerValue >= biggerValue}"); // true
    }

    public static void PrintExists(string methodName, MethodInfo? methodInfo)
        => Console.WriteLine($"Method '{methodName}' exists? {methodInfo is not null}");
}
```

Expected output:

```bash
Method 'op_LessThanOrEqual' exists? True
Method 'op_GreaterThanOrEqual' exists? True
Original: True, Inverted: False
Original: False, Inverted: True
```

A class that does not have operators overloaded will not have those methods. At least not if somebody not intentionally names a method like this. But then you can additionally check for the property `IsSpecialMethod` and when this returns `true` it should be an overloaded operator.

```
public class Program
{
    public class NoOperatorOverloading
    {
        public static void op_LessThanOrEqual() { }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var lessThanOrEqualMethod = typeof(InvertLogic<>)
            .GetMethod("op_LessThanOrEqual", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        Console.WriteLine(lessThanOrEqualMethod!.IsSpecialName); // false
    }
}
```